# QML: set AnimatedImage source without loading files in Resources

Tags: c++, qt, qml, gif

I have a QML form with:

```
AnimatedImage {
   id: gifImage
}
```

and I need to set its property `source`, without including files under Resources (because they are too heavy in mb). How can I still load those animated images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the local file path:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

AnimatedImage {
    id: animation
    source: "file:///path/of/your/file.gif" 
}
```